# popover does not reading html tag angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
var popover = '<u>Hi</u>: Some message.<br><br>' +
          '<u>New</u>: New msg.<br><br>' +
          '<u>Next</u>: Next Data.<br><br>' +
          '<u>Cancelled</u>: Remove service.<br><br>';

          $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(popover);



  <th class="col-info hidden-xs text-left">Status
  <span popover-placement="bottom" popover="{{ data }}"
   popover-trigger="click"
   class="pull-right"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
   </th>
```

//Does not read the html value even use $sce. Is there any conflication going on or anyother thing please assist thank a ton in advance.

Comment: Hi,do you want to print the output like this:                                  Status Hi: Some message.

New: New msg.

Next: Next Data.

Cancelled: Remove service.

Comment: lol @Saurav you can try these https://plnkr.co/edit/pu1j9haFQHwlETViGT3L?p=preview & https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ .

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ui.bootstrap`, which allows you to have templates within your popovers, so you don't need to compile it with `$sce`. Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dynamicPopover = {
    "templateUrl": "popover.html"
  };
  /* // you can have your data stored here
  $scope.dynamicPopover.msg = "Some message.";
  $scope.dynamicPopover.new = "New msg.";
  $scope.dynamicPopover.next = "Next Data.";
  $scope.dynamicPopover.cancelled = "Remove service.";
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" type="button" popover-placement="bottom-left" popover-trigger="click" class="btn btn-default">Status</button>

  <!-- Can be a separate file -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="popover.html">
    <u>Hi</u>: Some message.<br><br>
    <u>New</u>: New msg.<br><br>
    <u>Next</u>: Next Data.<br><br>
    <u>Cancelled</u>: Remove service.<br><br>
  </script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have created a sample jsfiddle. Please check it 
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v1jjeusg/)

you should use ng-bind-html attribute in your span tag

```
  <span ng-bind-html="data"></span>
```

I think it will help you